# SQLQuery to find dates in a specified range

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

Here is my Query for an **SQLite3 DB**

```
SELECT tddate, 
CASE tdtype 
  WHEN 'LOGIN' THEN MIN(tdtime) 
  WHEN 'SHUTDOWN' THEN MAX(tdtime) 
  ELSE NULL
END AS tdtime, tdtype, tdusername 
FROM TimeData
WHERE tdusername LIKE 'joe.shmoe' 
AND tddivision = 'divisionA' 
AND tddate > '6/1/2011' 
AND tddate < '7/5/2011' 
GROUP BY tddate, tdtype, tdusername 
ORDER BY tddate, tdtime DESC
```

results are dates that are from 6/30/2011 to 7/11/2011

I tried another query (much simplier to isolate the problem). I get the same results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TimeData
WHERE tddate > '6/1/2011' 
AND tddate < '7/5/2011' 
ORDER BY tddate DESC
```

Here is the DDL for the table

```
CREATE TABLE [TimeData] (
  [tdtag] CHAR(8), 
  [tdusername] CHAR(50), 
  [tddivision] CHAR(50), 
  [tddate] CHAR(10), 
  [tdtime] CHAR(8), 
  [tdipaddress] CHAR(14), 
  [tdtype] CHAR(8));
```

Comment: Let me guess .... tdtime is a String not a Date?

Comment: Your DDL for the table indicates that tdtime is CHAR(8).

Comment: tdDate is CHAR(10).  This is not a date, so it won't sort properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a true "date" data type and it's very picky about the format of date strings. Try specifying your dates in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. For more details, see the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: Never said it wasn't possible. Just said you have to format your dates correctly as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Tried that too and got 0 rows of data. SELECT * FROM TimeData WHERE tddate > '2011-06-01' AND tddate < '2011-07-05' ORDER BY tddate DESC

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: Is the existing data in the `tddate` column also formatted correctly?

Comment: When I run SELECT tddate FROM TimeData; I see the dates formatted as 7/1/2011, 6/30/2011

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: Then you have your answer. The date **strings** are not formatted correctly to support comparison operations.

Comment: how can I fix that? I imported all the data from a CSV file. In the CSV file, the dates are formatted as '2011-07-01', etc. Upon import, they change to 7/1/2011

Comment: @JoeStefanelli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1892/discussion-between-cocoa-dev-and-joe-stefanelli)

Comment: I reimported the data and now it matches the format we spoke of. However I am unable to run the query